# OAuth2.0Library to authenticate a user in an App xcode iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, authentication, oauth-2.0

i am working on Oauth 2.0 library for authenticating a user .I need to download the library files for ios.I followed the following url but   couldn't find the xcode libraries for this.

Click [here](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSource%2FTouch)!

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks
vikas

Answer (score 0):

Download the oauth 2.0 library files from the below link(select download as zip button):

https://github.com/dbloete/oauth-objc/downloads

Comment: @waseem Fastian Thte link you provided is fro OAuth 1.0 library i want to download OAuth 2.0 version library for iphone